# How to stop the tableview from loading before the api finishes call?(backbutton - case)

Tags: swift, api, tableview

I have a tableview and an api and api call function. I just use my apicall() function on the viewDidLoad() and Table.reloadData() once the data is received . This works fine on the first time when i am getting this screen.

I have a code inside the tableview.

```
zerointdeparturehour = String(departurehour[indexPath.row])
```

Which gets a time from an array that gets populated inside the api calling function.

Everything works fine as it should. The view loads , api gets called , gets data and tableview reloads and gets populated.

and if the api gets called again, all the array values created from the api call are removed with departurehour.removeAll(). (I used this so i can call the api again and again within the same screen for different dates)

BUT,

if i press the backbutton (default backbutton) to go back to previous page and if i try to come back to this page again, viewDidLoad() calls the apicall() function,

but i get error at

```
zerointdeparturehour = String(departurehour[indexPath.row]) - Index out of bounds.
```

Why does this happen ONLY when i move back from tableview page back to previous page and come back to this tableview page again? ( I know this happens because the departurehour array is nil at the moment because api hasnt filled the information inside it)

Why doesn't happen on the first time.

I get my row from Api as well, which works on the first time.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return flightcount // comes from api


    }
I do have a function to check if the flightcount is 0 or not and what to do when count is 0 .
```

The app was crashing because flightcount kept the value from previous screen and the table tried to load with that value and hence the crash.

**I fixed it with simply reinitialising it as 0.**

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        flightcount = 0
    }
```

On the previous screen. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. (both people who commented)

Comment: Add code for `numberOfRowsInSection` too. Also callback for your API call.

Comment: @Sharad Chauhan I get the row count from api as well.

Comment: So consider this scenario, your flightcount is greater that 0, so you will have one or more rows, then you are accessing departurehour which has no value, it will crash right ?

Comment: Are you using 0 as the default value. var flightcount = 0

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes. I think im keeping the flightcount at some value from previous screen.

Comment: @Zyfe3r Dont create any variable like flightcount. If you get an array of data from the api, store it in an array and user array.count in numberOfRowsInSection method

Comment: @Zyfe3r And dont use 2 different arrays in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRow method. Use same array

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I am using that variable because i need it for 4 5 places , i just used it make the code shorter. And i fixed it. Thank you and Sharad for giving the idea.

Comment: @Zyfe3r If you are using the same data in multiple places, then don't call the api in all places. Create a model class to store the details in a singleton class and access the data from multiple places

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I have codable class for all the data inside the api. Except for this one. I did it for some reason, and i forgot what was it about :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Synchronize `departurehour` and `flightcount` dataArray, you should not reload `tableview` until you have both the `arrays` ready.
2. Or add a check before accessing `departurehour`, whether it is empty or not:

`if !departurehour.isEmpty {
    zerointdeparturehour = String(departurehour[indexPath.row])
 }`

Comment: Don't use `!departurehour.isEmpty`. Check `departurehour.indices.contains(indexPath.row)`